# Select value on combobox with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, combobox

I have a combobox (select) and i want to select after a specified value
something like that

```
$("mySelect").select(myValue);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you want to select the `<option>` element associated with your value, you can use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2):

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="quux">Quux</option>
</select>
```

---

```
$("#mySelect").val("quux");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#yourselect").next().attr('selected', 'selected');
```

it will select next select after this one (yourselect)

so

```
<select id="your" />aa
<select id="yourselect" />bb
<select id="yourselect2" />cc
```

it'll select yourselect2

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#select').val('3');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
    <option value="1">ABC</option>
    <option value="2">DEF</option>
    <option value="3">XYZ</option>
</select>
```